# Text and backround colour with auctex has the same colour, how to change

Tags: auctex

In LaTeX mode with Auctex, I have a problem with `\textbf` and that is that the text inside the `{}` has the same colour as the background of the textbf field, as illustrated here:

[image]

This is only a problem in some themes, but how do I solve this?
It is only a problem with Auctex

Comment: You mean, the background is the same color of the text? In what theme?

Comment: Retro, Solarized Dark/Light and others

Comment: @JeanPierre ot os not the background of the editor, but of the textbf box

Comment: Put the point inside ``{}`` and hit `C-u C-x =`, look for the `face` property.  It should be `(font-latex-bold-face)`.  What do you see if you put point on it and hit `ENTER`?  Is `Background` also set?

Comment: @ArashEsbati that gives me not defining kbd macro

Comment: Hmm, for me, `C-h k C-x =` says: _`C-x =` runs the command `what-cursor-position` (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.

It is bound to `C-x =`.

`(what-cursor-position &optional DETAIL)`

Print info on cursor position (on screen and within buffer).
Also describe the character after point, and give its character code
in octal, decimal and hex. ... In addition, with prefix argument, show details about that character
in *Help* buffer._